# Unable to get latest version fom playstore app xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my function for get version number from playstore using application package name.

```
public async Task<string> GetLatestVersionNumber(string appName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appName));
            }

            var version = string.Empty;
            var url = $"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={appName}&hl=en";

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            {
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                    {
                        using (var responseMsg = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead))
                        {
                            if (!responseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                //throw new LatestVersionException($"Error connecting to the Play Store. Url={url}.");
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                var content = responseMsg.Content == null ? null : await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                                var versionMatch = Regex.Match(content, "<div[^>]*>Current Version</div><span[^>]*><div><span[^>]*>(.*?)<").Groups[1];

                                if (versionMatch.Success)
                                {
                                    version = versionMatch.Value.Trim();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                // throw new LatestVersionException($"Error parsing content from the Play Store. Url={url}.", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return version;
        }
```

My application version number is 49
and version name is 1.0.103
inside the content variable I have a large html code and I found that

```
<div class=\"IQ1z0d\"><span class=\"htlgb\">10+</span></div></span></div><div class=\"hAyfc\"><div class=\"BgcNfc\">Current Version</div><span class=\"htlgb\"><div class=\"IQ1z0d\"><span class=\"htlgb\">1.2.103</span></div></span></div><div class=\"hAyfc\"><div class=\"BgcNfc\">Requires Android</div><span class=\"htlgb\">
```

ON the versionMatch variable I am getting blank.how to solve this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly can you be elaborative as of now i understand there is some sort of a version mismatch!

Comment: versionMatch always return false.

Comment: So it always shows that the app is up to date is it?

Comment: it only returns version number of the app from playstore.

Comment: So on the basis of that you can update the app right?

Comment: you could refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073942/xamarin-android-how-to-get-google-play-store-app-version-number-using-dcsoup-nug , maybe help you

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to get the latest version of your app,

Create a variable for your application URL,

```
public const string _AndroidPackage = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={your app package name}";
```

Use below code to get the version number from play store,

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/soap+xml"));
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RESTKeys._AndroidPackage);
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RESTKeys._AndroidPackage);
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (result.Contains("Current Version"))
                            {
                                int startIndex = result.IndexOf("Current Version</div>") + 66;
                                result = result.Substring(startIndex);
                                int endIndex = result.IndexOf("</span>");
                                result = result.Substring(0, endIndex);
                                return result.Trim();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
```

Comment: RESTKeys._AndroidPackage does not exist on the current context

Comment: That is just a variable, you could use your own variable name or you can replace "RESTKeys._AndroidPackage" with your app play store URL.