# Get version number from play store xamarin android

Tags: web-scraping, xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.android

i've tried all the solution with [HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309564/how-to-get-app-market-version-information-from-google-play-store)

```
            newVersion = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@itemprop='softwareVersion']")
                              .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                              .ToList()
                              .First()
                              .Trim();
```

also i've tried this [dcsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073942/xamarin-android-how-to-get-google-play-store-app-version-number-using-dcsoup-nug)

```
 var doc = client.GetAsync("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + AppInfo.PackageName + "&hl=en_CA").Result.Parse();
                    var versionElement = doc.Select("div:containsOwn(Current Version)");
```

all the method return empty string
i noticed there is a changes of page play store and does not show the version number

Comment: if the page no longer shows the version number then obviously scraping the page for that data isn't going to work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jason, it show the version number , but only if show modal by clicking on "About this app => "

Comment: then you need to do some digging with your browser tools to figure out where that data comes from

Comment: i found solution to use regex (('/\[\[\[\"\d+\.\d+\.\d+/');
thanks